# Lanzar evento de un elemento oculto html

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Tengo esta tabla html:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td><img src="img/d1.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A1" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d2.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A2" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d3.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A3" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d4.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A4" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d5.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A5" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d6.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A6" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d7.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A7" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d8.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A8" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d9.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A9" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d10.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A10" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>B</td>
<td><img src="img/d1.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B1" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d2.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B2" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d3.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B3" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d4.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B4" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d5.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B5" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d6.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B6" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d7.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B7" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d8.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B8" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d9.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B9" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d10.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B10" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>C</td>
<td><img src="img/d1.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C1" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d2.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C2" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d3.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C3" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d4.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C4" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d5.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C5" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d6.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C6" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d7.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C7" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d8.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C8" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d9.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C9" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d10.png"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C10" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td>C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Como se pueden dar cuenta dentro de cada celda tengo una imagen y un checkbox que lo tengo oculto *display: none;* lo que necesito es que cuando de click en la imagen se lance el evento **onClick** que tiene el checkbox para tomar su valor y guardarlo en un array, como podría hacer esto. No voy a usar JQuery solo JavaScript.

Preguntando me comentaron que en lugar de ocultar el checkbox le diera un opacity de 0, lo hice pero no funcionó que podría tener mal?

Comment: es un poco raro eso, no? usar un evento click para un checkbox en lugar de mirar si esta chequedo o no

Comment: @blonfu como haria para que en el momento de dar click sobre la imagen se se seleccione el checkbox??

Comment: Lo mas fácil es poner las imágenes en un `label` y asociarlo con el `checkbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es solo guardar el `value` en un array al momento de seleccionar una imagen entonces solo necesitas darle un `push` a un array que declares, puedes asignar el `value` a las imágenes y mandar a llamar el evento `onClick`, te muestro un ejemplo:

```js
var arrImg = [];

function asignar(val){
  var valor = val.getAttribute("value");
  arrImg.push(valor);
  console.log(arrImg);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td><img src="img/d1.png" value="A1" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A1" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d2.png" value="A2" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A2" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d3.png" value="A3" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A3" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d4.png" value="A4" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A4" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d5.png" value="A5" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A5" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d6.png" value="A6" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A6" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d7.png" value="A7" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A7" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d8.png" value="A8" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A8" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d9.png" value="A9" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A9" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d10.png" value="A10" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="A10" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>B</td>
<td><img src="img/d1.png" value="B1" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B1" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d2.png" value="B2" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B2" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d3.png" value="B3" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B3" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d4.png" value="B4" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B4" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d5.png" value="B5" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B5" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d6.png" value="B6" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B6" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d7.png" value="B7" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B7" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d8.png" value="B8" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B8" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d9.png" value="B9" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B9" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d10.png" value="B10" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="B10" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>C</td>
<td><img src="img/d1.png" value="C1" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C1" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d2.png" value="C2" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C2" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d3.png" value="C3" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C3" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d4.png" value="C4" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C4" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d5.png" value="C5" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C5" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d6.png" value="C6" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C6" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d7.png" value="C7" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C7" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d8.png" value="C8" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C8" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d9.png" value="C9" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C9" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td><img src="img/d10.png" value="C10" onClick="asignar(this);"><input type="checkbox" class="ocultar chk_asiento" value="C10" onClick="asignar(this);"></td>
<td>C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Espero haber entendido y que te ayude. Suerte.

Comment: No me entendiste bien amigo, los checkbox estan ocultos, si te fijas cada uno de ellos tiene una clase css llamada ocultar, cuando se visualiza la página solo se muestran las imágenes, hasta ahi estoy bien. El problema es que cuando doy click en una imagen no se lanza el evento onClick del checkbox y necesito que ese evento se lance para tomar su valor y guardarlo en un array

Comment: De acuerdo, ahora entiendo lo que dices, hay inconveniente si agregas el mismo "value" a las imágenes?... En caso de que no haya inconvenientes modifiqué la respuesta agregando el value a las imágenes.